# How to use hash along with getopts in perl

Tags: perl

I have to use `GetOptions` in hash arrays.

My requirement is to write a Perl script with combination of multiple options 
for example:

```
test.pl -a mango -s ripe -d <date value>
```

or

```
 test.pl -a apple -s sour
```

where `mango`, `ripe`, `apple`, `sour`, etc. are user input which is also used to bind a variable in a SQL `WHERE` clause of a `SELECT` query to generate a report.

I this code

```
use vars qw ($opt_a $opt_s $opt_d)
Getopts('a:s:d:')
```

Now I am facing an issue in writing hash

```
my %hash = @ARGV
```

is the above hash definition is correct? Is there any better way to use hash?

Comment: why do you want to do that? You've already processed the command line. You do not need to do `my %hash = @ARGV;`. Are you saying you want to use the latter instead of using Getopts?

Comment: Hi Imran actually the values with command line arguments are input to my select query in where clause to generate a report and @ARGV will store the arguments in its inbuilt array so based on the given combination I want to generate a report that's why i want to use has hash. Please suggest me any solution for this via any sample code.

Comment: if you want the keys to be "-a", "-s", and "-d", then yes, the hash definition is correct. If a user does not pass all the required parameters, you need to check for that, e.g. if they pass -d without a value or if they do not pass -d at all. That is why using a pre-tested module is a good idea.

Comment: I already developed the logic for combination of parameters, can you please tell me how to pass these incoming values to the bind variable of the where clause of select query 
for eg  select col1,col2 from table_name 
where col1 = :bind1 
  AND col2 = :bind2
Thanks in advance

Comment: That would be a different question and is well documented in the DBI documentation (http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.625/DBI.pm).

Comment: @imran. No, this definition is not correct. It cannot handle a lot of possible argument formats. I would suggest to use the `getopts` to create a hash directly.

Comment: @TrueY His requirements only mention "key value" combinations on the command line. If the user of his script is going to type the arguments in a different way (i.e. no spaces or skip a value), he needs to check for that, of course.

Answer (score 6):

No, this hash "definition" is not correct. What happens if `-amango -sripe` command line is given? You will get a hash with "-amango => -sripe". If `-amango -s ripe` is given the size of @ARGV would be odd and a warning will be presented (like `Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ./x.pl line 6.`).

You can directly create a hash with getopts. Try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

my %opts;
getopts("a:s:d:", \%opts) or die;

while (my($k, $v) = each %opts) {
    print "$k => $v\n";
}
```

Output calling with `-amango -s ripe` args:

```
a => mango
s => ripe
```